# flask. Как перехватывать исключение RequestEntityTooLarge?

Tags: python, flask

При загрузке файла можно установить ограничение на размер загружаемого файла. Для этого есть инструмент установки ограничения размера:

```
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 #* 1024 * 1024
```

и отлов прерывания:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import RequestEntityTooLarge
```

Например, приведенный ниже код работает и дает возможность обработать ситуацию.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request

from werkzeug.exceptions import RequestEntityTooLarge

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 #* 1024 * 1024

@app.route('/')
def upload():
    return render_template("file_upload_form.html")


@app.route('/success', methods=['POST'])
def success():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f_name = None
        try:
            # start request parsing
            f = request.files['file']
            f.save(f.filename)
            f_name = f.filename
        except RequestEntityTooLarge as e:
            # we catch RequestEntityTooLarge exception
            app.logger.info(e)

        return render_template("success.html", name=f_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

В случае же подключения модуля `flask-form` прерывание "заваливает" выполнение кода, несмотря на `try`.  Не подскажете что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простите, нашел ответ:

```
@app.errorhandler(413)
def request_entity_too_large(error):
    return 'File Too Large', 413
```